# Getting an error about memory, while trying to save dataset

Tags: r, memory

I'm trying to save my dataset in R using write.csv command, however, I get an error about the memory after some time. I believe it is because of the size of the dataset (around 4GB), but I can't really reduce it (need it full for my research goals). Do you have any ideas, how to solve it (other command or another option, etc).
P.s. memory limit allocated to R is at 8GB. The desktop version of R (not server).
Code: `write.csv(mydata,"combined1.csv", row.names = TRUE)`
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `fwrite` from package data.table.

Comment: @Roland Add your comment as an answer so that ProjectAvatar can select it as their chosen solution.

Comment: @Mus No, thanks. I'm pretty confident we have numerous duplicates already. I just can't be bothered to search for one.

Answer (score 0):

The solution, as posed by Roland, is to use `fwrite` from the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)

fwrite(...)
```